# Export variable into python from C++ using boost.python

Tags: c++, python, variables, boost, export

I have, for example, a varibale in c++:

```
const float Pi = 3.1415926535898f;
```

What is the best way to export it into python-module using boost.python?

I want to access it as variable in global scope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems that it can be easily done using:

```
boost::python::scope().attr("Pi") = Pi;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do so in Pybind11?

Answer (score 0):

PyModule_AddObject if you want inject it to a module imported from python file.